# Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this piece of jquery controlling animating tab

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-animate, toggle

I'm trying to create a tab that animtes and shifts the position of a container. The first part of the code works perfectly shifting the tab to the position of 0%, however, the second part doesn't and I can't figure out why. I'm not an expert with jquery and this code has been adapted from code I've found on this site. Any help from a jquery wizard would be helpful.

Thanks

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".seefullscreentab").click(function(){
                if($(".seefullscreentab a").hasClass('opentab')){
                    $(".scrollpage-container").animate({ 'marginTop': '0%'}, 500);

                    $(".seefullscreentab a").toggle();

                } else {
                    $(".scrollpage-container").animate({ 'marginTop': '-15%'}, 500);
                    $(".seefullscreentab a").addClass('opentab');
                }   
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The offending line would appear to be:

```
$(".scrollpage-container").animate({ 'marginTop': '-15%'}, 500);
```

If i go to developer tools and physicall enter the marginTop to be '-15%' (it's original starting position), it works perfectly. For some reason, the jquery won't shift it there.

Please help!

Comment: Suggest you create a demo that replicates problem. Are there more than one `.seefullscreentab a` in page? Are you intending to look for a specific one? too many unknowns for us to help

Comment: There is only one '.seefullscreentab' which is a tab that has classes opentab and closetab wrapped within a div. I have others on the page that work with this if else statement performing similar functionality but can't get this one to work. I know it's vague. May have to create a demo if I can't solve it. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Have added a test so you can see what I'm trying to do at the folliowing link: the3rdobject.com/test-site/index.html - the top tab works perfectly, however it is performing the function slightly differently. The bottom tab is what I would like to close back to it's original position and it only opens currently. Please help - my jquery is not up to scratch! Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have an if/else conditional statement. The way JS works is that your code will trigger one branch of this code but not the other. That's why half is working and half is not.

I can see what you are trying to do - enable the toggling through the conditional statement but that isn't how it works. jQuery has a couple of properties called [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), [.slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) and [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) you should review. They all work similarly.

I tried to modify your code to work with slideToggle. This may not be what you are trying to achieve but it would show you the proper way to construct your code:

```
$('.seefullscreentab').click(function() {
  // This would part would toggle the tab closed
  $('.scrollpage-container').slideToggle( 500 , function() {
    // This part would move the container's margin after it's closed
    // Put the original margin in CSS and put override here
    $('.scrollpage-container').css('marginTop': '0%');
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi there. I see what you're saying bu tI do have if else statements working elsewhere perfectly as in addition to opening and closing the tab, the wording on the tab toggles too. I tried getting it to work with slideToggle but no joy as yet. Will try and construct a test so you can see what I'm trying to achieve. Perhaps that will be more helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi there, have added a test so you can see what I'm trying to do at the folliowing link: http://www.the3rdobject.com/test-site/index.html - the top tab works perfectly, however it is performing the function slightly differently. The bottom tab is what I would like to close back to it's original position and it only opens currently. Please help - my jquery is not up to scratch! Many thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get that bottom tab to come up over the top of the entire screen?